# How to insert an event on google calendar without using android intents?

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, calendar, android-contentprovider

Basically, I'm booking appointments for the patients the main thing I want is that as the appointment is booked the event is set on google calender on the user phone. I'm passing the time and date as params in the code below that are selected by the patient while booking an appointment.

Now when I run my code I'll get an error **"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DTSTART cannot be empty."**

Here is the method that I've write for it:

```
private fun calenderEvent(makeAppointmentEntity: MakeAppointmentEntity) {
    val GLOBAL_DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    val appointmentDate = "23-4-2021"

    val event = ContentValues()
    event.put("calendar_id", 1)
    event.put("title", "Appointment" + makeAppointmentEntity.bookedSpecialization)
    event.put("description", "Appointment of ${makeAppointmentEntity.txtDoctorName}")
    event.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().id)
    event.put("dtstart", makeAppointmentEntity.appointmentDate)
    event.put("dtend", makeAppointmentEntity.appointmentDate)
    event.put("allDay", 0) // 0 for false, 1 for true
    event.put("eventStatus", 1)
    event.put("hasAlarm", 1) // 0 for false, 1 for true

    val eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events"
    val eventUri = context!!.applicationContext.contentResolver.insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), event)
    val eventID = eventUri!!.lastPathSegment!!.toLong()
    val minutes = 120

    val reminders = ContentValues()
    reminders.put("event_id", eventID)
    reminders.put("method", "1")
    reminders.put("minutes", minutes)

    val reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders"
    context!!.applicationContext.contentResolver
            .insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminders)
}
```

Comment: The error suggest that `dtstart` is empty, did you check the value to make sure it is not?

Comment: @tyczj no sir it's not empty I'll check it through debugging **23-4-2021** is receiving as **dtstart**  value, but app again crashes and I'll get the same error.

Comment: The documentation says its value should be a timestamp in milliseconds